# nokogiri only return one item

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I call the method "**read**" and only return one item from xml file

the method "**read**" return:

```
9
3
max
date
5
```

and should return all items from xml

how do I get the whole xml from the method read?

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

def create
  var = 0  
  while var < 10
    builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do 
      item {
        data var
        port '3'
        length 'max'
        date 'date'
        limit '5'
      }
      var += 1  
    end
  end
  return Nokogiri::XML(builder.to_xml).root.to_xml
end

def read    
  doc = Nokogiri::XML(create)
  doc.xpath('//item').each do |item|
    data = item.at_xpath('./data').content
    port = item.at_xpath('./port').content
    length = item.at_xpath('./length').content
    date = item.at_xpath('./date').content
    limit = item.at_xpath('./limit').content

    puts data
    puts port
    puts length
    puts date
    puts limit
  end
end

read
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `read` method is fine. The problem is that the XML document is not what you think it is. If you look at output of your `create` method, it creates only this document:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<item>
  <data>9</data>
  <port>3</port>
  <length>max</length>
  <date>date</date>
  <limit>5</limit>
</item>
```

This is because you are creating (and re-creating, and re-creating) your document INSIDE your `while` loop. Instead, you want to do something like this:

```ruby
def create
  var = 0  
  builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do
    root do
      while var < 10
        item {
          data var
          port '3'
          length 'max'
          date 'date'
          limit '5'
        }
        var += 1  
      end
    end
  end
  return Nokogiri::XML(builder.to_xml).root.to_xml
end
```

Note that I have added a `<root>` element to wrap all your items, since an XML document can only have one root element, and you appear to be adding multiple `<item>` elements to it.

---

Additionally, may I suggest that instead of your `while` loop you use the more Ruby-esque:

```
10.times do |var|
  # no need to var += 1 here
  # the rest of your code
end
```